# Assign incremented variables to list of hosts with ansible

Tags: ansible

What i want should be dead simple but I can't seem to find an answer. I want to run math simulations with different inputs. I have access to a list of 40 servers(i do not have root privilege) so my idea is to test 40 different set of coefficients on them simultaneously. It's not clear how I could set the variables up with a `for loop` like statement in ansible and assign each of them to a different server. Ideally I want the variables list to be floating numbers similar to what `a = numpy.arange(.0,1.,.1)` would give me. Any ideas?

The server group is setup like this:

`[computingCluster]
cic[1:40]`

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of what command should be run on the servers? So cic1 might have `python myProgram 0.1` cic1 might have `python myProgram 0.2` etc

Comment: exactly like what you said, i'm also ok with hardcoding the parameter name inside the codes with jinja2 templates so that they get substituted automatically while being copied over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    me@pc:~/Ansible/playbooks/test_iterate$ ansible-playbook test0.yml 

    PLAY ***************************************************************************

    TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
    ok: [srv-db1]
    ok: [srv-db-temp]

    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [srv-db-temp] => {
        "msg": "101"
    }
    ok: [srv-db1] => {
        "msg": "102"
    }

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    srv-db-temp          : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
    srv-db1              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

test0.yml:

```
     hosts: srv-dbs
      vars: 
        - priority_start: 100
      tasks:
       - debug: msg="{% for thishost in play_hosts %}{% if inventory_hostname==thishost %}{{ priority_start + loop.index }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let create a playbook that has two plays:

- First `Play` will generate host variable file from template for each host.
- Second `Play` will execute actual tasks on the hosts.

Directory Structure:

```
/tmp/ansible
├── [host_vars]
├── inventory
├── my_template.yml.j2
└── playbook.yml
```

Inventory File:

```
[computingCluster]
cic[1:10]
```

Template `my_template.yml.j2` for loading host variables ( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data ):

```
coefficient: {{ item.0 }}
```

Playbook with two plays:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: Create Variable File for Each host
      template: src=my_template.yml.j2 dest=host_vars/{{ item.1 }}
      with_indexed_items: "{{ groups['computingCluster'] }}"


- hosts: computingCluster

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Load Host Specific Generated Variables
      include_vars: host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname }}


  tasks:

    - debug: var=coefficient
```

And here is the result `ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml`:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK: [Create Variable File for Each host] ************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=(0, 'cic1'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(1, 'cic2'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(2, 'cic3'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(3, 'cic4'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(4, 'cic5'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(5, 'cic6'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(6, 'cic7'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(7, 'cic8'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(8, 'cic9'))
ok: [localhost] => (item=(9, 'cic10'))

PLAY [computingCluster] *******************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [cic1]
ok: [cic5]
ok: [cic4]
ok: [cic2]
ok: [cic3]
ok: [cic6]
ok: [cic9]
ok: [cic10]
ok: [cic8]
ok: [cic7]

TASK: [debug var=coefficient] *************************************************
ok: [cic1] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "0"
    }
}
ok: [cic2] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "1"
    }
}
ok: [cic3] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "2"
    }
}
ok: [cic4] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "3"
    }
}
ok: [cic6] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "5"
    }
}
ok: [cic5] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "4"
    }
}
ok: [cic7] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "6"
    }
}
ok: [cic8] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "7"
    }
}
ok: [cic9] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "8"
    }
}
ok: [cic10] => {
    "var": {
        "coefficient": "9"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
cic1                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic10                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic2                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic3                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic4                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic5                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic6                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic7                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic8                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
cic9                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

You can always play around with `coefficient` variable using jinja templates ...

References:

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-a-list-with-an-index

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I guess I could tweak your answer somehow to make it work but it is not what i'm looking for as is. And your result would only appear that way if you execute that playbook the second time. The way `ansible` works is that it loads all the variable files in the beginning. And since none of the variable files exists at the beginning of the first run, ansible has no host variable files to load. So you have to separate your two plays into two playbooks, which isn't ideal.

Comment: @LingxiaoXia, I think you are mistaken here - I tested this locally and it worked perfectly for me. Just see the output. This playbook has two runs inside  - during the first run variable files are being generated and in second play files are loaded as expected. If you want I can share with you test environment.

Comment: Well i might be mistaken but it seems like ansible loads variables for plays in the same playbook all at once(before it runs any play) on my machine. Could you please delete all the variable files and try again? my ansible version is 1.9.3

Comment: @LingxiaoXia, changed playbook to explicitly load variables from generated files. Please check `pre_tasks` section together with `include_vars` task ( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html )